# Asp-net info from NLog wrapped in class library

Tags: c#, asp.net, nlog, class-library

I have a class library wrapping a NLog implementation with some own methods:

```cs
public static class MyLogger
{
        private static readonly NLog.Logger Logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        public static void Log(EventType eventType, Exception exception, string message)
        {
            LogLevel level = LogLevelHelper.GetLogLevel(eventType);
            Logger.Log(level, exception, message);
        }

        public static void LogInfo(string message)
        {
            Logger.Info(message);
        }

        public static void LogError(Exception exception, string message)
        {
            Logger.Error(exception, message);
        }
}
```

Then I have an Asp Net WebApp with some calls to the class library methods:

```cs
[ApiController]
public class Runner
{
        [HttpGet]
        public void Foo()
        {
            MyLogger.Log(Logger.Enums.EventType.Error, new System.Exception(), "Log with eventype error");
            MyLogger.LogInfo("Log info");
            MyLogger.LogError(new System.Exception(), "Log error");
        }
}
```

And in that project (*Runner*) I have the `Nlog.config` that `MyLogger` takes:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      internalLogFile="${basedir}\logs\internal-nlog.txt">>

  <targets>

    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File"
            layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${message}${exception:format=ToString}"
            fileName="${basedir}\logs\logfile.txt"
            keepFileOpen="true"
            encoding="utf-8" />

    <target name="logconsole" xsi:type="Console" />

    <target name="logdb"
        xsi:type="Database"
        connectionString="${appsettings:name=DatabaseConfiguration.ConnectionString}"
        commandType="StoredProcedure"
        commandText="[dbo].[NLog_AddEntry_p]"
        >

      <parameter name="@id"                  layout="${guid}" />
      <parameter name="@user"                layout="${aspnet-user-identity}" />
      <parameter name="@createdOnUtc"        layout="${date:universalTime=True}" />
      <parameter name="@eventType"           layout="${level}" />
      <parameter name="@url"                 layout="${aspnet-request-url}" />
      <parameter name="@machineName"         layout="${machinename}" />
      <parameter name="@applicationName"     layout="${iis-site-name}" />
      <parameter name="@serverClass"         layout="${callsite}" />
      <parameter name="@serverMessage"       layout="${message}" />
      <parameter name="@serverStack"         layout="${exception:format=ToString,StackTrace}" />
      <parameter name="@clientMessage"       layout="${aspnet-request}" />
      <parameter name="@clientStack"         layout="" />
    </target>

  </targets>

  <rules>

    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logconsole" />

    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile" />

    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" maxlevel="Fatal" writeTo="logdb" />

  </rules>
</nlog>
```

But of course, the log info is taken from `MyLogger` and not from `Runner`.

All the `aspnet-*` and `iis-*` tags are empty.

How can I take this information from the Asp Net proyect?

Comment: You are probably missing `<add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>` as shown in the Wiki-Guide: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2#2-create-a-nlogconfig-file . Else try enable the NLog Internal Logging: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging

Comment: @RolfKristensen I added the `<add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>` and in internal log I got `Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Abstractions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: Ahh sorry thought you were developing a AspNetCore-application. Then you should instead use `<add assembly="NLog.Web" />`https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web